# Is using a non-balance protected lithium-ion battery ok?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, cell-balancing, battery-balance

I am building a project where I use 4 stepper motors. Since they require a lot of power I am considering using a Lithium-Ion battery for them.

This is what I was looking at:

https://www.onlybatteries.com/showitem.asp?ItemID=22517.128&cat1=&uid=

Here are the specs from the link:

Li-Ion Size: 3 x 18650 (cylindrical)
Capacity: 3500 mAh
Chemistry: Lithium Ion (Li-Ion)
Working Voltage: 11.1v / 10.8v
Peak Voltage: 12.6v
Cut off voltage: 7.5V
Max Charging Current: 2.1 Amp
Max Discharging Current: 4.2 Amp Limited by Polyswitch
Length: 2.75" (70mm)
Width: 2.17" (55mm)
Height: 0.8" (18mm)
Weight: 5.3 Oz

Features:
No memory effect
Longer storage life then NiMH Batteries
Light weight and higher energy density than any rechargeable battery
Installed PCB (4 Amp) will prevent the battery pack from over charge (> 12.6V), over discharge(< 7.5 V), Overdrain (> 4.0Amp) and Short Circuits. It helps protect battery chemistry integrity and prolongs battery life.
4.2 Amp polyswitch installed to limit max. discharging current at 4.2 A and to protect wrong polarity.
The battery module is wrap by PVC shrink and with 22 G wire leads

The battery looks good, I like that it has protection circuit that prevents over charge and over discharge. It also prevents short circuiting the battery.

However it does not have the connector for balanced charging. How much of an issue is that? Will that cause me problems down the line?

Comment: That's a pretty big pack to not have balance taps.

Comment: "Can", "must" and "should" are all different things.   Some people like to view the Grand Canyon from about 10 feet back... others like to hand their toes over the ledge for the best view.   If you're making a one-off for your own purpose that you'll be using sporadically and that you can manually check the cells for balance occasionally, you're probably OK skipping it.  If you're doing a production unit for a customer, that's a whole other thing....

Comment: What is the chance that the pack will eventually become unbalanced? Nobody can tell you exactly. But if it does become unbalanced, then one or two cells may become over-charged or over-discharged. It would be nice if you could at least check the voltage of all the cells periodically to assess. But it looks like they are covered with shrink wrap.